# Why iphone and ipad doesn't reproduce video in django template?

Tags: ios, iphone, django, ipad

I try to do a web to reproduce videos, and work in all device except iphones and ipads.
The template is this:

```
  <video controls autoplay muted id="my-video" width="98%" height="auto"><!-- <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay muted width="300" height="264" data-setup="{}">-->
          {% for video in videos %}
            {% if video.pk == pagina_actual  %}
              <source src={{video.video.url}} type="video/mp4"></source> 
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </video>
```

If in the src I put a url like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A" the video is play, but whem I put this tag of django don't work.

Why in the others devices work the reproduction and this two devices not?
How can fix this?

Comment: The url should be in quotes - `src="{{video.video.url}}"`

Comment: No, in this form neither work

Comment: I solved the problem. THe problem is django server, but when you put django project in apache, ios devices reproduce the videos without problems